# Cannot import quandl in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, quandl

I have spyder (Python2.7) and spyder3 (Python3.5) installed on Ubuntu 16.04. I was able to import quandl in spyder (Python2.7) setup, but not in spyder3 (Python3.5). Do you have any suggestions?

Below is the error returned in the terminal when testing Python 3.5:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import quandl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'quandl'
>>> import Quandl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'Quandl'
```

Comment: I can install and import quandl on 3.6.

Comment: try to install quandl for python3, just download the source and install it with "python3 setup.py install"

Comment: Many thanks to all for your answers! Already fixed the problem. Ended up with using "pip3 install quandl" for Python3.5 associated with spyder3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would seem your Python3.5 installation does not have quandl installed.

You can install quandl easily via pip using:
`pip install quandl`

(or `pip3 install quandl` depending on your system's configuration)

Answer (score 15):

try lowercase. it works for in 3.5.2

Answer (score 5):

I was following a tutorial where it said

       `import Quandl`

instead I used `import quandl`
and it worked
I had the same problem although I have installed quandl correctly using `pip install quandl`

 hope this helps somebody

Comment: i am using python 3.6.5

Answer (score 1):

On systems that have both 2.x and 3.x installed you need to adjust your use of the pip command as follows:

To pip install package_name to target your 2.x python use:
        pip install package_name

To pip install package_name to target your 3.x python use:
        pip3 install package_name

Do not rename / reassign pip and pip3, they are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `pip3 install quandl`will work here.

However, you can find explicitly your pip script inside your python3 directory.
then run the following command:

`pip install quandl`

you can rename or alias `pip` script inside the python3 directory to `pip3` for better use in the future.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone still looking at this problem.

just tried to install on an AWS ubuntu community machine learning instance.

could not get this to install on python 2.7 by pip install or by git clone xxx and python setup.py install

pip3 install quandl worked first attempt.

another reason to migrate from python 2.7 to python 3.x before end of life for python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

try install pip3 install Quandl but for importing use :-

`import quandl`  ##it works

Answer (score 0):

*Quandl* actually changed their namespace from **Quandl** (in v.2) to **quandl** (in version 3).

So if you upgrade an existing package with:

> pip install --upgrade quandl

The least painful way to fix the import issues is to change: `import Quandl` to `import quandl as Quandl`, wherever you have previously used it in your application.

On the other hand, for a fresh install you can just use this command:

> pip install quandl

You can read more in their official Github repository [readme](https://github.com/quandl/quandl-python).

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quandl'